# ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS will not launch Aweather after the last update. 1-26-18

Tags: 16.04, lts

I have ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and Aweather will not launch after the last update.  I have used Aweather for years without any problems.  How do I fix this?

Thank you for all your responses and help.  I have resolved my issue by reloading ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and the problem has gone away.  I have no other details as to what caused the issue at this time.  1-31-18

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question, I mean what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: The US government did something and in the process they broke something, what I meant to say is in detail in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817083/my-weather-widget-is-not-working)

Comment: @GulamMohammed That link is two years old. OP problem just started today and was presumably working yesterday.

Comment: What does `uname -r` reveal for the current kernel version? As a short term fix reboot and from grub **Advanced Options** menu pick the next oldest kernel and Aweather will hopefully work OK.